# The $T^{i+1}\text{ and }\ T^{i}$ Kernel of Matrix

Tags: matrices

For i > 0, let $K_i = ker T^i$ ($T^0$means the identity transformation) (T is linear mapping and V is n-dimensional).

Show that for each i, $K_i ⊆ K_{i+1}$,

and deduce that there exists a non-negative integer r such that $K_r = K_{r+1}$. Prove that $K_r = K_{r+j}$ for all $j ≥ 1$. Hence, or otherwise, show that $V = K_r ⊕ T^r(V)$.

for v $\in ker(T^i)$, $T^{i+1}(v)=T(T^i(v))=T(0)=0$. Then we have $v\in (ker(T^{i+1}))$

So for exist such that $K_r=K_{i+1},$ it is to show there is $ker(T^{r+1})\subseteq$ $ker(T^r)$ But how to do it?

And why we have $K_r = K_{r+j}$ ?

Comment: Is $T$ a linear mapping?

Comment: Is $V$ finite-dimensional?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @sigmabe How to use the dimension argument?

Comment: Yes I know the dimension can not grow forever by the rank-nullity theorem but how to rigidly show that $K_r=K_{r+1}$ at some point. and $K_r=K_{r+j} $

Answer (score 1):

We have for every $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ the inclusion $K_i\subseteq K_{i+1}$ and so $\dim(K_i)\leq \dim(K_{i+1})$. So $\dim (K_{i})$ is an increasing sequence bounded by $n$ and so it gets constant for some $i=r$. So we get $\dim (K_{r+i})=\dim (K_{r})$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and so by $K_r\subseteq K_{r+i}$ we get $K_r=K_{r+i}$.

Comment: So when it is shown that there exists r then we have $dim(K_{r+i})=dim(K_r)$ since it remains constant. Then how to show the direct sum?

Comment: For the direct sum, does it equal to $ker ⊕ image$?